# "npm ERR! invalid semver" while trying to publish npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm-publish, npm-package

`npm ERR! code EBADSEMVER npm ERR! invalid semver: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:` 
I've already tried re-install node and semver. It doesn't works

Comment: can you share your npm or package.json command?

Answer (score 4):

without logs or package.json file I can only assume there's something wrong with version in your package.json file. Check if you have "version"in there that follows major.minor.patch mask:

```html
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
}
```

Or you trying to publish same version twice.

[About semantic versioning npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning)